# Changing a list vector to numeric, with NAs in correlation test - R

Tags: r, correlation, na

I have a large data set with 601 columns and 185 rows where I need to get a correlation coefficient for each column 1:600 with the column 601 and store those correlations somewhere.

To do this I have done the following code

```
x=sr3coco[,601]
y=sr3coco[,1:600]

corr.values <- vector("list", 600)
for (i in 1:length(y) ) {
  cor.values[[i]] <- cor.test(x, y [[i]], method="s")
}
```

However! My y variable has a lot of NA's in it so R is recognising y as a list vector and I need it to be numeric in order to do the correlation test and I can't figure out how to make it ignore the NAs and just correlate with the values which are there! Please help me, bare in mind that I am an R newbie.

Here are a few rows of what x and y look like

x - 1.22E-01,   -5.95E-01,  -1.90E+00,  -8.36E-01,  4.13E-01

y-  NA,        NA,  1.83E+00,   4.40E-01,   2.11E-01

Comment: Could you post some sample data? Like the first few rows of `x` and of some `y` columns.

Comment: I added a couple of the data points. A lot of the y has NAs in it, but I need to keep them in.

Comment: You can try removing the NA's and their equivalent in `x`. For example, `cor.test(x[!is.na(y[ ,i])], y[ ,i][!is.na(y[ ,i])], ...`

Comment: I still just get the error message 'y' must be numeric vector. Is there a way before running the correlation test to set up my y as a numeric ? at the moment it is coming up as a list vector when I do y=sr3coco[,1:600], I thought it was because of all the NA's because when I cut the data down and run the cor.test on a section of the data with no NA, it comes up as numeric